# tkinter Label Text save to database

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I'm trying to insert the contents of the label into the database, the text of the label changes every time, I need to insert this entry into the database every time the text of the label changes

```
def add_data():
    try:
        mycursor.execute("insert into info(name) values(%s)", (labelID['text']))
        con.commit()
        result = messagebox.askyesno('Data added successfully')
        if result:
            labelID.configure(text='')

        else:
            pass
    except:
        messagebox.showerror('Error')
        return

def qr_webcam_reader():
ret, frame = capture.read()
if ret:
    # resize frame
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (400, 280))
    # decode frame
    for code in decode(frame):
        decoded_data = code.data.decode("utf-8")
        decode_data = code.data.decode("utf-8")
        if decoded_data:
            rect_pts = code.rect
            pts = np.array([code.polygon], np.int32)
            cv2.polylines(frame, [pts], True, (255, 0, 0), 3)
            cv2.putText(frame, str(decoded_data), (rect_pts[0], rect_pts[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            labelframe2.configure(text=str(decoded_data))
            labelID['text'] = str(decoded_data)
```

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is.

Comment: @acw1668, I added a change to the code, there is a method that reads the qr code, after I write the data to the label text , now I need to insert this data into the database

Comment: You have already asked similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76873940/python-insert-data-into-table-by-tkinter).  BTW, why don't you call `add_data()` just after updating the label inside `qr_webcam_reader()`? I would suggest to pass `decoded_text` into `add_data()` instead of getting the text from the label inside `add_data()`.  Also don't show dialog box inside `add_data()` if it is called inside `qr_webcam_reader()`.

Comment: @acw1668, what you suggest would be great, I could not implement such a solution, therefore, to begin with, I wrote the decode_data result in the label after I try to insert it into the database

Comment: @acw1668 , should i create a loop and define mycursor.execute('insert into info(name) values(%s)', (decode_data)) ?